# How to make conditional merging on a list of lists in R?

Tags: r, list, function, merge

I have a list. 
 
I want to compare elements pairwise and then merge the elements if they meet a criteria 
 
sample list:

```
[[1]]
[1] "466" "1758" "975"

[[2]]
[1] "1528" "185"  "975" 

[[3]]
[1] "1528" "185"  "975" 

[[4]]
[1] "2892" "758"  "971" 

[[5]]
[1] "1321" "274"  "969" 

[[6]]
[1] "1321"  "274" "969" 

[[7]]
[1] "115"  "1321" "969" 

[[8]]
[1] "1321" "441"  "969" 

[[9]]
[1] "504" "61"  "948"

[[10]]
[1] "504"  "61" "948"
```

Suppose the criteria is simply: if element 1 is equal to element 2 then merge them and remove the second element from the list.

Expected output:

```
[[1]]
[1] "466" "1758" "975"

[[2]]
[1] "1528" "185"  "975" "1528" "185"  "975" 

[[3]]
[1] "2892" "758"  "971" 

[[4]]
[1] "1321" "274"  "969" "1321"  "274" "969" 

[[5]]
[1] "115"  "1321" "969" 

[[6]]
[1] "1321" "441"  "969" 

[[7]]
[1] "504" "61"  "948" "504"  "61" "948"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

We could create a logical index with `duplicated`, extract the elements from the `list` and concatenate with `Map`, update the `list` and extract only those elements based on the index

```
i1 <- duplicated(lst1)
i2 <- duplicated(lst1, fromLast = TRUE)
lst2 <- lst1
lst2[i1] <- Map(c, lst1[i1], lst1[i2])
lst2[!i2]
#[[1]]
#[1] "466"  "1758" "975" 

#[[2]]
#[1] "1528" "185"  "975"  "1528" "185"  "975" 

#[[3]]
[#1] "2892" "758"  "971" 

#[[4]]
#[1] "1321" "274"  "969"  "1321" "274"  "969" 

#[[5]]
#[1] "115"  "1321" "969" 

#[[6]]
#[1] "1321" "441"  "969" 

#[[7]]
#[1] "504" "61"  "948" "504" "61"  "948"
```

---

Or using `split`

```
lst2[i1] <- lapply(split(lst1[i1|i2], lst1[i1|i2], drop = TRUE), unlist)
```

#### data

```
lst1 <- list(c("466", "1758", "975"), c("1528", "185", "975"), c("1528", 
"185", "975"), c("2892", "758", "971"), c("1321", "274", "969"
), c("1321", "274", "969"), c("115", "1321", "969"), c("1321", 
"441", "969"), c("504", "61", "948"), c("504", "61", "948"))
```